# define the length of data which is passes as a props in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to define or control the length of data which coming from api. for example I have 50 data set for ploting in the  chart but i want to define that only 30 data set will be ploted on chart.

I have created a chart component Like

```
class BarChart2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (

        
      <VictoryChart domainPadding={{ x: 15 }}>
        <VictoryAxis dependentAxis />

        <VictoryBar data={this.props.data} barWidth={20} alignment="start" />
        <VictoryAxis
          style={{
            axisLabel: { padding: 0 },
            tickLabels: {
              textAnchor: "start",
            },
          }}
        />
      </VictoryChart>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, I am rendering the BarChart Component in Child Component Like

```
<BarChart2 data={sampleData}/>
```

Sample Data

```
sampleData=[ { "x": 1, "y": 134 },
    { "x": 2, "y": 125},
    { "x": 3, "y": 178 },
    { "x": 4, "y": 186 },
    { "x": 5, "y": 115},
    { "x": 6, "y": 189 },
    { "x": 7, "y": 112 },
    { "x": 8, "y": 196 },
    { "x": 9, "y": 110 },
    { "x": 10, "y": 128 },
    { "x": 11, "y": 112 },
    { "x": 12, "y": 170 },
    { "x": 13, "y": 190 },
    { "x": 14, "y": 110 },
    { "x": 15, "y": 128 },
    { "x": 16, "y": 112 },
    { "x": 17, "y": 170 },
    { "x": 18, "y": 19 },
    { "x": 19, "y": 196 },
    { "x": 20, "y": 10 },
    { "x": 10, "y": 110 },
    { "x": 21, "y": 112 },
    { "x": 22, "y": 140 },
    { "x": 23, "y": 150 },
    { "x": 24, "y": 100 },
    { "x": 25, "y": 108 },
    { "x": 26, "y": 122 },
    { "x": 27, "y": 170 },
    { "x": 28, "y": 116 },
    { "x": 29, "y": 187 },
    { "x": 30, "y": 12 },
    { "x": 31, "y": 144 },
    { "x": 32, "y": 120},
    { "x": 33, "y": 118 },
    { "x": 34, "y": 156 },
    { "x": 35, "y": 11},
    { "x": 36, "y": 19 },
    { "x": 37, "y": 192 },
    { "x": 38, "y": 191 },
    { "x": 39, "y": 160 },
    { "x": 40, "y": 118 },
    { "x": 41, "y": 132 },
    { "x": 42, "y": 120 },
    { "x": 43, "y": 180 },
    { "x": 44, "y": 150 },
    { "x": 45, "y": 128 },
    { "x": 46, "y": 142 },
    { "x": 47, "y": 120 },
    { "x": 48, "y": 179 },
    { "x": 49, "y": 126 },
    { "x": 50, "y": 150 },]
```

Comment: do `array.slice()`

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "control" or "define" the number of points that will be plotted.  You *could* just throw an exception if your component receives more than 30 data points, or render a message saying "Maximum 30 data points allowed" instead of rendering the chart.  That's probably not what you want though.

**Display the first 30 items**

As @nisharg suggested in the comment, you can operate on a subset of the array, like so:

```
<VictoryBar data={this.props.data.slice(0,30)} barWidth={20} alignment="start" />
```

This would take the first 30 elements from `this.props.data`, and not display anything else.

**Display a sampling of 30 of the 50 items**

Maybe you want something more sophisticated, like sampling the input.  You could create a helper function like so outside of your class:

```js
const originalData = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
const maximumPointsToShow = 6

function sample(data, maxPoints){
    const freq = data.length / maxPoints
    
    const sampledData = []
    for (let i = 0; i < maxPoints; i++){
        const sampledIndex = Math.floor(freq * i)
        sampledData.push(data[sampledIndex])
    }
    return sampledData
}

console.log(sample(originalData, maximumPointsToShow))
```

And use it in your component like this:

```
<VictoryBar data={sample(this.props.data, 30)} barWidth={20} alignment="start" />
```

I'll leave it up to you as to how to handle edge cases like not enough data, `maxPoints = 0` etc.